# Is it possible to break page on a double line break in the minted environment?

Tags: page-breaking, minted

For a project, I am printing a large amount of source code using Minted. Certain blocks, such as CSS blocks, are fairly short, but are split across pages, which means they are not as readable. Is it possible to get Minted to only insert a page break where there is a double line break in the code?

Comment: What if there isn't a double line break, but the page space is not enough?

Comment: @Alenanno Then breaking anywhere would be acceptable, but almost all my code has fairly regular double line breaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plan here is first set interlinepenalty to 10000 so no linebreaking happens normally and then modify the underlying fancyverb to detect a blank line and if so encourage a page break.

The example uses a very small page, just to show the effect.

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}

\setlength\topskip{\baselineskip}
\setlength\textheight{12\baselineskip}


\makeatletter
%\showoutput

\def\@wasblank{\PYG {err}{BLANK}}
\def\foo{\aftergroup\ffoo}
\def\ffoo{\goodbreak}% or \clearpage or whatever
\let\zzzz\FV@PreProcessLine
\def\FV@PreProcessLine{%
  \ifx\FV@Line\@empty
    \def\FV@Line{BLANK}%
  \fi
  \ifx\FV@Line\@wasblank
    \def\FV@Line{\aftergroup\aftergroup\aftergroup\foo}%
  \fi
  \zzzz}

\begin{document}

%\showoutput
\noindent x1\\x2\\x3\\x4\\x5\\x6\\x7\\x8\\x9\\x10\\x11\\x12
%\tracingall

{
\interlinepenalty10000 %
\begin{minted}{json}
[
  {
    "type": "Room"
    "type1": "Room"
    "typesad": "Room"
    "typde": "Room"
    "tydpe": "Room"
  },

  1111,
  "aaaaa", 
  "aaaasda", 
  "aaaaa", 

  2222,
  "2aaaaa" ,

  333,
  "zzzz" 
]
\end{minted}
}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there any way I can use this in conjunction with breaklines?

Comment: @CharlieHarding I'd expect so, did you try?

Comment: I tried enabling the [breaklines] option of minted in the MWE, and it stopped page breaking the code at all.

Comment: Even without enabling `breaklines`, for the long `minted` listing I have, this code only puts `BLANK` on the blank lines, and renders the entire listing onto one page, never breaking and running off into infinity at the bottom.